# How to add null in ARRAY in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract values from JSON objects present in the BigQuery table.
Problem Statement- I have a table with json values in one of the columns. I want to extract values from the json when there is value to the key is array and array has matching values. Output should be in ARRAY as per where condition given in the query written below and when there is an object it should return value in STRING. Please refer below output table and query.
I have a table as below

```
  json    
 -------- 
 "fruit":[{"apples":"5","oranges":"10"},{"apples":"5","oranges":"4"}] 
 "fruit":{"apples":"1","oranges":"15"}   
 "fruit":{"apples":"5","oranges":"1"}  
 "fruit":[{"lettuce":"7","kale": "8"}]
```

I am writing below query

SELECT
json,
(
SELECT
ARRAY(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(fruit,
'$.oranges'))
FROM
UNNEST(ifnull(json_extract_array(json,
'$.fruit'),
[json_EXTRACT(json,
'$.fruit')])) fruit
WHERE
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(fruit,
'$.apples') = "5") AS fruit_value
FROM
TABLE

It gives an error like `Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field fruit_value`
I want output like below

```
|  json.   | fruit_value|  
| -------- | -------- | 
| "fruit":[{"apples":"5","oranges":"10"},{"apples":"5","oranges":"4"}]| [10,4]| 
| "fruit":{"apples":"1","oranges":"15"}| null| 
| "fruit":{"apples":"5","oranges":"1"}| 1 | 
| "fruit":[{"lettuce":"7","kale": "8"}]| null|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below

```
#standardSQL
select json,
  array(
    select json_extract_scalar(x, '$.oranges') oranges,
    from unnest(ifnull(json_extract_array(json, '$.fruit'), 
    [json_extract(json, '$.fruit')])) x  
    where json_extract_scalar(x, '$.apples') = '5'
  ) as fruit_value
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select '{"fruit":[{"apples":"5","oranges":"10"},{"apples":"5","oranges":"4"}]}' json union all
  select '{"fruit":{"apples":"1","oranges":"15"}}' union all
  select '{"fruit":{"apples":"5","oranges":"1"}}' union all
  select '{"fruit":[{"lettuce":"7","kale": "8"}]}' 
)
```

the output is

[image]